# Question analysis so amazing

Tags: radicals, fake-proofs

[image]

How this process has been calculated in a manner added.

Comment: The mistake is already in the second step: $$4-\frac92\neq\sqrt{\left(4-\frac92\right)^2}$$ since $\;\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\;$ , and in this case $\;4-\frac 92<0\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$4-\frac 92\not=\sqrt{\left(4-\frac 92\right)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{\left(4-\frac92\right)^2}=-\left(4-\frac92\right)$$

More generally for real $a,$  $$\sqrt{a^2}=|a|=\begin{cases} a &\mbox{if } a\ge0  \\ -a & \mbox{if } a<0\end{cases}$$